# Problem in Delphi/BDE App - Ora-942 table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, delphi, oracle10g, oracle11g, bde

I can not explain this, i keep gettign the Message "Ora942-table or view does not exist" from one pc while i dont get it from the other one, both access the same Schema and Database and has the same alias in tnsnames.ora.

The table exists in the Database, the Schema name is the write one.

Any Idea what could be the reson for that?

thank you

Comment: It's 2011 and you're still using BDE? :-(

Comment: @Warren I swear its not my choice :) We are moving to Anydac but some old customers still need support with old versions of the product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

On the PC where it didnt work the BDE Configuration was different!

**Configuration->Driver->Native->Oracle->Driver Flags** was Empty. It should be set to **1**